# I don't want the navbar be over jumbotron

Tags: html, css, navbar

So I've got this problem that my jumbotron goes under the navbar and I want to put it just below with some padding between them.
Here is my code: https://codepaste.net/ditsxf

[This is how it looks like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DY8SM.png)

Comment: Please provide your code here, along with your css code in order for us to help you

Comment: you're missing </div></div> at the bottom of your code, before the <script=

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The classes from a bootstrap added a `position: fixed;` to your navbar. It means, that your navbar is **always visible** at the top of your screen all the time, even when you are scrolling down.

There are 2 ways to fix this:

1. Remove `.navbar-fixed-top` class from your `nav` component, but then you won't see your navbar at the top when you scroll down.
2. Add some `margin-top` to your container element.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this to your .css file:

```
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
}
```

Or whatever the height of the nav bar is.